# Matching an string to regular expression when both the string and the regular expression has re reserved characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings which may or may not match with a certain template.
I want to separate the strings that match with the template from the rest.
I could convert the template to regular expression.
But my template(which is eventually converted to a regex) and strings may have the regular expression reserved characters.
How can I match  the strings with the template in this scenario.

Ex:

Strings :

- ```
  abc[ ere er \ sfdf asdf.
  ```
- ```
  def[ ere we \ sfdf asdf.
  ```
- ```
  ghi[ ere qs \ sfdf asdf.
  ```

Template :

```
(anything)[ ere (anything) \ sfdf asdf.
```

Regex I used:

```
.+ ere .+ \ sfdf asdf.
```

But this does not output that all 3 strings are matching with template.

Comment: I tried to format your code using backticks and `<pre>`. If I messed anything up, please edit to fix or rollback (but I do recommend using fixed width, otherwise it's pretty hard to read).

Comment: Try `.+?` to make your captures non greedy. Presumably (anything) doesn't include spaces?

Comment: (anything) can include space too.

Comment: Try double escaping the the backslash ``\\`` and escape the dot ``\.``

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input strings and the template, would you please try:

```
r'^.+?\[ ere .+? \\ sfdf asdf\.$'
```

Comment: answer is perfect for your question.

`r"^.+?\[\sere\s.+?\s\\\ssfdf\sasdf\.$"`

Here is just little modification, it's better to use '\s' for space because it will make sure that you are providing only one space.